# Assign IP address using ip

Tags: linux, ip

How would I assign an IP address usng `ip` (the Linux tool)? I've been doing it with `ifconfig` so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ip addr add <IP address> dev <device name>`

[IP man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)

Answer (score 3):

From the ip man page:

```
ip addr { add | del } IFADDR dev STRING
```

Therefore:

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ip addr add a.b.c.d/mm brd + dev iface
```

`brd +` means asking iproute2 to automatically calculate the broadcast address based on the subnet information. E.g.:

```
ip addr add 192.168.4.55/24 brd + dev eth0
```